# Returning common Result as CompletionStage<Result> in play

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework, synchronous

In my view function I may return a `Result` or a `CompletionStage<Result>` based on whether or not the post/get data is valid or not:

```
if (data.hasErrors()) {
    return badRequest(myview.render(data));
} else {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> calculate(data)
                .thenApply(result -> ok("Got result: " + result.toString()));
}
```

The problem is that I can't have the view function return both types, so it seems logical to return the async version and somehow wrap the `badRequest` (or any other common response in `play.mvc.Results`) in a `CompletableFuture`.

I can do something like:

```
return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "")
            .thenApply(result -> badRequest(myview.render(data)));
```

But I'm hoping for a more elegant solution.
Anything?

I'm using play version 2.5.4.

Comment: Why not `return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(badRequest(myview.render(data)));`?

Comment: @acelent I ended doing that, but I was hoping to be able to somehow return `Result` instead of wrapping it with `CompletionStage`.